# Upload and add a content editor web part in Search Center sub site using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, search-results, file-upload, enterprise-search

How to upload and add a Content Editor web part in Search Center sub site using PowerShell?I am having a .dwp file in my filesystem and I want to upload this into the results.aspx page of my search center sub site within my site collection.
I coded the below line of code, but it fails /_catalogs/wp doesnt found error in PowerShell.

```
    Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction   
     SilentlyContinue
     [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName  
    ("Microsoft.SharePoint")
    $webURL = "http://srvr1:123/sites/RC/sc"
    $web = Get-SPWeb $webURL
    $srcPath="C:\My\Scripts\ConfigureSearch"
    $siteUrl="http://srvr1:123/sites/RC/sc"

    $libraryFolder="_catalogs/wp"
     $libraryUrl=$siteUrl + "/" + $libraryFolder
       $srchCSSWPfileName = "SearchCSSChnages.dwp"

     function UploadFile
      {
         param([string]$srcPath,
         [string]$fileName,
         [string]$libraryUrl,
        [string]$libraryFolder)
       try
         { 
        $web=get-spweb $siteUrl
          $folder=$web.GetFolder($libraryFolder)         
        $file=get-childitem ($srcPath + "\" + $fileName)

      #$srchCSSWPfileName=get-childitem ($srcPath + "\" + $fileName)
         $files=$folder.Files
      #$files.Add(($libraryUrl+"/" + $fileName), $file.OpenRead(), $true)
      $files.Add(($libraryUrl+"/" + $srchCSSWPfileName), $file.OpenRead(), 
     $true)
     #check in only when files are checked out, when it's publishing page
      if($files[$fileName].checkOutStatus -ne "None")
    {
       $files[$fileName].checkIn("checked in by Powershell by me")
        $files[$fileName].publish("published by Powershell by mee")
        start-sleep -s 5
        $files[$fileName].Item.File.Approve("Approved by Powershell by 
    me")
    }
   }
   catch [Exception]
   {
     write-error $_
   }
   finally
  {
  if($web -eq $null)
   {
    $web.dispose()
   }
 }           
}
 UploadFile -srcPath $srcPath -fileName $srchCSSWPfileName -libraryUrl 
 $libraryUrl -libraryFolder $libraryFolder
```

Comment: Web Part gallery is present in the root site collection. Looks like you are using the subsite url  `http://srvr1:123/sites/RC/sc`. Perhaps it should be `http://srvr1:123/sites/RC/_catalogs/wp`

Comment: That did not work